# Why is the usage of mutex correct in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I was asked a question about mutex before, the code works fine, but I am confused about this result：

```
::std::mutex s_mutex;
void funcA()
{
    s_mutex.lock();

    printf( "funcA \n" );

    s_mutex.unlock();
}

void funcB()
{
    s_mutex.lock();

    funcA();

    printf( "funcB \n" );

    s_mutex.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    funcB();

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine and print what I did not etxpect：

```
funcA 
funcB
```

But why? This func is called in main thread and seems to call lock twice.

Comment: Note that a `std::recursive_mutex` does support this calling pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I just confused about this case.

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::mutex::lock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If `lock` is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, **the behavior is undefined**: for example, the program *may* deadlock. An implementation that can detect the invalid usage is encouraged to throw a `std::system_error` with error condition `resource_deadlock_would_occur` instead of deadlocking.

Comment: I also write try catch code around funcB, but no exception( std::system_error ).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Quentin, locking a `std::mutex` from one thread several times leads to an undefined behavior. To allow a thread to lock an mutex object several times, you can use [std::recursive_mutex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/recursive_mutex/).

> A recursive mutex is a lockable object, just like mutex, but allows
>   the same thread to acquire multiple levels of ownership over the mutex
>   object.
>
> This allows to lock (or try-lock) the mutex object from a thread that
>   is already locking it, acquiring a new level of ownership over the
>   mutex object: the mutex object will actually remain locked owning the
>   thread until its member unlock is called as many times as this level
>   of ownership.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about recursive mutex,I confuse why mutex looks like recursive in this case

Comment: "looks like" is the key word here -- just because it appears to be working correctly, doesn't mean it is; it just means that the symptoms of the malfunction are not easy to detect.